# PortAudio generating distorted sound on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, linux, audio, raspberry-pi, portaudio

I'm developing a simple synth using C++ and PortAudio.

The problem is the sound is beautiful when I compile and use on Windows and distorted when I build and run on my Raspberry Pi.

PC: Win8, using cygwin

Raspberry: v1.2 B+, using Arch armv6 (no server X)

Here is the sound produced. To record the Raspberry I connected the jack output to the digital input of my computer. This is the same sound I'm hearing on the headphone. It's no problem with the equipament, the Front_Center.wav test was successful.

It's a sine wave with 440hz frequency.

Windows:
http://picosong.com/6vif/

Linux:
http://picosong.com/6vi5/

The build output:

```
g++ -c -Wall -Iinclude -o build/main.o -g src/main.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -Iinclude -o build/wave.o -g src/wave.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -Iinclude -o build/wave_generator.o -g src/wave_generator.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -Iinclude -o build/audio_manager.o -g src/audio_manager.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -Iinclude -o build/midi_message.o -g src/midi_message.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -Iinclude -o build/midi_manager.o -g src/midi_manager.cpp
g++ -o bin/rasksynth -g build/*.o -lportaudio -lportmidi
```

Someone can help me?

EDIT:

Oh, sorry. My code is open source. Here it is if anyone wants to check it out.

https://github.com/faelcorreia/rasksynth

Comment: What's the sampling rate and bit rates you're using for port audio and the raspberry pi?

Comment: @yun.cloud I'm using 44100.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Raspberry Pi but did you have to configure I2C or I2S for it (any configurations for communication)?

Comment: @yun.cloud No, I didn't. I don't know if I need because I'm using the default speaker out. As I said, normal wav files are played flawlessly. I added my project git to the question.

Comment: Sounds like it's being aliased, I would double check that. And it looks like you're printing out statements at the same time you're outputting sound? Try commenting those out too. EDIT: NEVERMIND just looked over your main.cpp file, don't need to comment those out.

Comment: I don't know if it's something about aliasing because the square sound is ugly too, and the square wave don't suffer with aliasing problems (I think).

Comment: Usually when I got that sound when I was working with uC's is when I was getting an aliased signal, incorrect bit rate, or debugging through print statements. I think print statements slow down the processor so your waveform generation would get slowed down. Sorry haven't been much help, hard to debug a uC you don't have haha. Why would a square wave not suffer aliasing problems?

Comment: @yun.cloud No problem yun, every assistance is valid. So, I think there is no aliasing problem with Square wave because all my sample is about 1 and -1 and there is no curves on the wave. I'm right?

Comment: Thanks for understanding, and aliasing is when the waveform is not properly sampled at the right points (this is working on the x axis, not y axis). Lets say you have a 440 Hz sine wave and square wave. These will have the same phases as they both move at 440 cycles/sec. With aliasing, you need 2x the sampling rate to properly recreate the waveform so in this case it would be 880 Hz. However, if you have a sampling rate of 440 Hz you'll actually get 0 Hz, 220 Hz you'll get 220 Hz.   In summary: x axis - time, y axis - amplitude, aliasing deals with time